# Difference between a random variable and its expected value

Tags: notation, random-variables

In this paper by Rohe et al.,

*Rohe, Karl; Chatterjee, Sourav; Yu, Bin*, [**Spectral clustering and the high-dimensional stochastic blockmodel**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/11-AOS887), Ann. Stat. 39, No. 4, 1878-1915 (2011). [ZBL1227.62042](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1227.62042).

they show that a certain random matrix has the same eigenvectors as its expected value with high probability. They propose the following illustrative example.

Consider a matrix $W \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ with i.i.d. Bernoulli$(1/2)$ entries. We thus have, for $i\neq j$,
$$
(WW)_{ij}\sim \mbox{Binomial($n,1/4$)}.
$$

Next, they state that

> ...for any $i,j$, $(WW)_{ij}-\mathbb E[(WW)_{ij}]=o(n^{1/2}\log(n))$. Thus, the Frobenius distance from the squared matrix to its expectation is
>   $$
> \|WW/n^2-\mathbb E[WW]/n^2\|_F=\frac{1}{n^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}((WW)_{ij}-\mathbb E[WW_{ij}])^2}=o\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^{1/2}}\right).
> $$

However, $WW$ being a random variable, this does not make sense to me. The result of that difference should be yet another random variable. Even if this result is supposed to be a value attained with high probability, I'm not sure I can see how the got that particular asymptotic bound.

What exactly do the authors mean with this notation? How did they get to that asymptotic equality?

Comment: Presumably, the $o$ bound holds for any realization of $W$, which is made of $0/1$ entries.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's a good point, but $(WW)_{ij}-\mathbb E[(WW)_{ij}]$ is maximized for $(WW)_{ij}=n$, which does not yield $o(n^{1/2}\log n)$.

Comment: May be they meant expectation of $(WW)_{ij} - \mathbb{E} [(WW)_{ij}]$?

Comment: @mihalid That would be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $WW_{ij} - \mathbb{E}[WW_{ij}] = o(n^{1/2}\log n)$ then $$(WW_{ij} - \mathbb{E}[WW_{ij}])^2 = o(n\log^2 n).$$
Summing this over all $i,j$, we get
$$\sum_{ij} (WW_{ij} - \mathbb{E}[WW_{ij}])^2 = o(n^3\log^2 n).$$
Taking the square root, we get
$$\sqrt{\sum_{ij} (WW_{ij} - \mathbb{E}[WW_{ij}])^2} = o(n^{3/2}\log n).$$
Dividing by $n^2$, we get
$$\frac{1}{n^2}\sqrt{\sum_{ij} (WW_{ij} - \mathbb{E}[WW_{ij}])^2} = o\left(\frac{\log n}{\sqrt{n}}\right).$$

Here, $WW$ is not a random variable, but a particular realization of the random variable. Confusingly perhaps, both are denoted in exactly the same way. Let me give a simpler example. Suppose that $X \sim \mathrm{Bin}(n,1/2)$. Then with high probability, $n/3 \leq X \leq 2n/3$. Therefore with high probability, $|X - \mathbb{E}[X]| \leq n/6$.

---

Since $WW_{ij} \sim \mathrm{Bin}(n,1/4)$, a Chernoff bound shows that with high probability, $WW_{ij} - \mathbb{E}[WW_{ij}] = o(n^{1/2} \log n)$ for all $i,j$. (In fact, we can replace $\log n$ with any function which is $\omega(\sqrt{\log n})$.) Therefore, the bound in your quote holds whp.

Comment: Thanks, although I remain confused. The initial equality certainly implies the final bound. However, it is precisely that equality that puzzles me. In what sense is $(WW)_{ij}-\mathbb E[(WW)_{ij}]$ equal to $o(n^{1/2}\log(n))$? As suggested in the comments, it could mean that any realization will satisfy the equality. However, it does not seem to be the case, e.g. for  $(WW)_{ij}=n$.

Comment: This part is missing from your quote, so it's impossible to know. Presumably, this bound only holds whp.

Comment: Well, in the paper they just state it like that. They don't give a derivation or further context (I believe). I'll continue reading to see if it becomes clear later. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The paper is missing the phrase "whp" at some point. A routine application of the Chernoff bound shows that $WW_{ij}$ is $o(n^{1/2} \log n)$-close to its expectation, for all $i,j$ at once, whp.

Comment: You're right. I think that's all there is to it.